# Is she trying to scam me or is it real love

Tags: banking, scams

I met this girl online. She wants me to sign up to an online bank called find Finn. She is going to put three or five thousand dollars in it to buy a plane ticket to come to see me and to get our engagement ring.

By the way I'm 20 and she is 30 which I don't mind. I have to ask for picture to see what she looked like as I have not met here in person. I did try to call, but she never said a thing, was just coughing, the call was cut short and I have not tried again.

Is this a scam? or is she for real?

Answer (score 9):

DO NOT SEND OR ACCEPT MONEY.

Sorry, it sounds that you are very emotionally invested and your text is hard to read but this very much looks like a scam.

Comment: thanks for your help and sorry if it is hard to read I'm dyslexic and never learned how to do sentences right.

Answer (score 4):

This is so obviously a scam that I’m worried you feel the need to ask.

1. You haven’t seen her
2. You haven’t talked to her

Those 2 points are enough on their own for you to realize that no one intends to get engaged with you.
But then:

3. Why would you need to open an account for her to put money in it? Don’t listen to her rationalization, think for yourself
4. It appears ‘Find Finn’ does not exist, at least google hasn’t heard about it. I’m sure you went to an actual website but that doesn’t mean anything.

So far ‘she’ didn’t ask for actual money but many things can still happen:

- This ‘bank’ will get a lot of personal details from you, possibly including bank details
- She will have some excuse later as to why you need to put money in it
- She actually appears to send money and you can withdraw/transfer it and she asks you to forward some/all of it to elsewhere. Then you are either a money mule or her transaction gets cancelled later and you’re out of money.
- A number of other scams

Answer (score 2):

This is a scam. There is no love. You will lose money.